# How to run assembly code when macOS protects you against it?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, assembly

I am currently doing a computer course where I have to run assembly inside of C++. In my class, everyone is running it in Windows and they have no problem running the code (I was able to do it on Windows too). When I execute the code on my Mac using Xcode, I get `XC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)` which I think means that macOS is protecting me from running system calls.

When debugging the line that crashes the program, I think it is the `call printf` line that is giving me the error as the code executes and completes successfully.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

char format[] = "%s %s\n";
char hello[] = "Hello";
char world[] = "world";

int main()
{

    __asm
    {
        mov  eax, offset world
        push eax
        mov  eax, offset hello
        push eax
        mov  eax, offset format
        push eax
        call printf
        pop  eax
        pop  eax
        pop  eax

    }
}
```

To get this 32-bit code to work on my 64bit Mac, on Xcode, I went to `Build Settings -> Architectures` and selected `32-bit Intel` in order to compile it.

How would I fix the `EXC_I386_GPFLT` runtime error on my Mac running 10.13.2?

Note: In Xcode, I created a macOS Command Line Tool.

Edit: 
I forgot to say that I tried disabling rootless (SIP) and ran Xcode when logged into the root user. That still did not work.

Comment: ``__asm``: Visual C++ specific

Comment: I wonder how you got this to compile.  C Symbols are decorated with leading underscores on OS X, so your function call should be `call _printf` to even link.  Same for all the variables.

Comment: @fuz @asesh when I do `call _printf` I get Use of undeclared label '_printf' and that is with the `__` and without it.

Comment: Very interesting.  This all doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @fuz, could it be because it is running inside C++ and not just pure assembly?

Comment: The basis of your question is incorrect: MacOS does not prevent you from running assembly code.

Comment: @fuz "This all doesn't make a lot of sense to me" - that's how I feel every time I see anything apple related

Comment: @iProgram The error should not result from using inline assembly, however I do not understand the rules of this dialect of inline assembly so it's hard for me to understand where the problem comes from (stack misalignment seems like a possibility).  I advise beginners to learn assembly by programming in actual assembly, not inline assembly as the latter is very confusing unless you are already pretty firm in assembly programming.

Comment: Your code is very different from the inline assembly shown in Clang's user manual: http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline-asm

Comment: See also the comment below this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31689418/7328782

Comment: The error you get indicates that you did an illegal memory access (it's a *general protection fault*).  It does not indicate that assembly code is forbidden or something and running it as root won't fix anything (quite on the contrary, running code as root makes the damage larger if something goes wrong).  I am not sure what causes this error though.

Comment: Stack alignment issue. Read the question above. Same applies to 32-bits macOS.

Comment: @Asesh `__asm { }` is valid syntax in Xcode for `x86` and `x86-64` assembly.